# Concatenate a a string and integer to make a new column for each dataframe in a list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to make a new column for each dataframe in a list of dataframes called "RING" which contains the word "RING" + the another column called "No".

here is my solution so far

```
df_all = [df1,df2,df3]

for df in df_all:
    df["RING "] = "RING" + str(df['No'])
    
df_all
```

Is there away that doesn't require a for loop?

Comment: There is definitely no way to vectorise an operation on a list of dataframes, if that's what you're asking. If you wish you can use `map`, which will avoid the explicit loop syntax

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
df_all = [df1,df2,df3]

for df in df_all:
    df["RING"] = "RING" + df["No"]
    
    # If df["No"] is not of type string, cast it to string:
    # df["RING"] = "RING" + df["No"].astype("str")
    
df_all
```

Comment: if I use .astype("str") and it is already a string does that matter?  I ask as sometimes the data is read in as an integer because that particuarl batch only contained numbers and at other times it is mixed so becomes a string

Comment: Then use the `.astype("str")` version. It does nothing if the column is already of type string but will convert everything to string otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

- you can concat all dataframes in the list to get one df (then work with it):

```
df_all = [df1,df2,df3]
df = pd.concat(df_all, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df["RING "] = "RING" + df['No'].astype(str)
```

- if you want to come bak and get separate dataframes, you can do this:

```
df_all = [df1,df2,df3]
df1['df_id'] = 1
df2['df_id'] = 2
df3['df_id'] = 3

df = pd.concat(df_all, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df["RING "] = "RING" + df['No'].astype(str)

#--> 
df1 = df.loc[df['df_id'].eq(1)]
df2 = df.loc[df['df_id'].eq(2)]
df3 = df.loc[df['df_id'].eq(3)]
```

- if you don't want use concat, you can try list comprehension, usually faster than for loop:

```
df_all = [df1,df2,df3]

def process_df(df):
    df["RING "] = "RING" + df['No'].astype(str)
    return df

processed_df_all = [process_df(df) for df in df_all]
#df1 = processed_df_all[0]
```